# Putting two flowcharts using tikz,

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to put two flowchart in my paper. I try to use tikz. Each one seprately works. But while I try to put both of them in two figures I face with this error:

```
<argument> ...f@ya \pgf@y =\pgfshapeaspectinverse
\pgf@xa \advance \pgf@y by...
```

The first flowchart is:

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows}
\tikzstyle{decision}=[draw,diamond]
\tikzstyle{line}=[draw,-latex']
\tikzstyle{elli}=[draw,ellipse]
\tikzstyle{block}=[draw,rectangle]
\scriptsize
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [elli, align=center] (dc) {Run DCOPF};
\node [decision, below of=dc, align=center, text width=4em,node distance=7em] (checkCong) {Is there any\\ congested\\ line?};
\node [block, below of=checkCong, align=center,node distance=6.5em] (Init) {$\nu=0$\\$\theta^0=\theta^{DCOPF}$};
\node [block, below of=Init, align=center,node distance=4em] (masterIni) {Run master problem\\ without considering benders cut\\ to initialize $\lambda,\,p_g,\,u$};
\node [block, below of=masterIni, align=center,node distance=4em] (IncNu) {$\nu=\nu+1$};
\node [block, below of=IncNu,node distance=4em] (sub) {Solve subproblem};
\node [decision, below of=sub,node distance=5em, align=center] (phiCheck) {Is\\ $\phi>0$?};
\node [block, below of=phiCheck, align=center,node distance=7em] (benders) {Generate infeasibilty cuts\\ and forward it\\ to master problem};
\node [block, below of=benders,node distance=4em] (master) {Solve master problem};
\node [block, below of=master,node distance=3em] (update) {Update $\lambda^{\nu},\,p_g^{\nu},\,u^{\nu},\,\theta^{\nu}$};
\node [decision, below of=update, align=center,node distance=6em, minimum height=5mm] (convCheck) {Convergence \\ check};
\node [elli, below of=convCheck,node distance=7em] (end){end};
\node [decision, left  of=end,xshift=-10em,yshift=20em,align=center] (maxIter) {Is\\ $\nu>\nu^{max}$?};
%arrows
\path [line] (dc)--(checkCong);
\path [line] (checkCong)--(Init);
\path [line] (Init)--(masterIni);
\path [line] (masterIni)--(IncNu);
\path [line] (IncNu)--(sub);
\path [line] (sub)--(phiCheck);
\path [line] (phiCheck) -- node [near start, xshift=1em] {Yes} (benders);
\path [line] (benders)--(master);
\path [line] (master)--(update);
\path [line] (update)--(convCheck);
\path [line] (convCheck)--node [near start, xshift=1em] {Yes} (end);
\path [line] (convCheck)-|node [near start, yshift=0.5em] {No}(maxIter);
\path [line] (maxIter)|-(IncNu);
\path [line] (phiCheck)--++  (3,0) node [near start, yshift=0.5em] {No} |- (convCheck);
\end{tikzpicture}
and the second one is:
\begin{tikzpicture}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows}
\tikzstyle{decision}=[diamond,draw]
\tikzstyle{line}=[draw,-latex']
\tikzstyle{elli}=[draw,ellipse]
\tikzstyle{block}=[draw,rectangle]
\scriptsize
\node [block, align=center] (masterm) {Solve master problem} ;
\node [block, below of=masterm, align=center, node distance=3em] (subm) {Solve sub problem};
\node [decision, below of=subm, align=center, node distance=6em] (check) {Is there\\ infeasibility?};
\node [elli, below of=check, align=center, node distance=6em] (end) {End};
\node [block, left of=end, xshift=-8em, yshift=10em, align=center] (cut) {Generate infeasibility cut};
%arrows
\path [line] (masterm)--(subm);
\path [line] (subm)--(check);
\path [line] (check)-- node [near start, xshift=1em] {No} (end);
\path [line] (check) -| node [near start, yshift=0.5em] {Yes} (cut);
\path [line] (cut) |- (masterm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.sx!  unfortunately, the way the error messages are shown doesn't give the full context that would show exactly *what* control sequence is undefined.  if you can cut-and-paste the relevant lines from the full log (it is a separate file, but the line number, 845 as shown on this summary, should be there too), that would be helpful.  also, even more helpful would be a compilable ["minimal (non)working example" (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that we can try to reproduce the problem directly.

Answer (score 1):

You either:

1. Have auxillary files left over from a previous run, in which case I would try removing the temporary files and recompiling.
2. Or you have libraries are not up to date in which case I'd recommend updating to TeXLive2014.

---

Adding a `\documentclass{article` along with `\usepackage{tikz}` makes your code compile just fine (along with some scaling to get things to fit):

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows}
\tikzstyle{decision}=[draw,diamond]
\tikzstyle{line}=[draw,-latex']
\tikzstyle{elli}=[draw,ellipse]
\tikzstyle{block}=[draw,rectangle]
\begin{document}
\scriptsize\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\node [elli, align=center] (dc) {Run DCOPF};
\node [decision, below of=dc, align=center, text width=4em,node distance=7em] (checkCong) {Is there any\\ congested\\ line?};
\node [block, below of=checkCong, align=center,node distance=6.5em] (Init) {$\nu=0$\\$\theta^0=\theta^{DCOPF}$};
\node [block, below of=Init, align=center,node distance=4em] (masterIni) {Run master problem\\ without considering benders cut\\ to initialize $\lambda,\,p_g,\,u$};
\node [block, below of=masterIni, align=center,node distance=4em] (IncNu) {$\nu=\nu+1$};
\node [block, below of=IncNu,node distance=4em] (sub) {Solve subproblem};
\node [decision, below of=sub,node distance=5em, align=center] (phiCheck) {Is\\ $\phi>0$?};
\node [block, below of=phiCheck, align=center,node distance=7em] (benders) {Generate infeasibilty cuts\\ and forward it\\ to master problem};
\node [block, below of=benders,node distance=4em] (master) {Solve master problem};
\node [block, below of=master,node distance=3em] (update) {Update $\lambda^{\nu},\,p_g^{\nu},\,u^{\nu},\,\theta^{\nu}$};
\node [decision, below of=update, align=center,node distance=6em, minimum height=5mm] (convCheck) {Convergence \\ check};
\node [elli, below of=convCheck,node distance=7em] (end){end};
\node [decision, left  of=end,xshift=-10em,yshift=20em,align=center] (maxIter) {Is\\ $\nu>\nu^{max}$?};
%arrows
\path [line] (dc)--(checkCong);
\path [line] (checkCong)--(Init);
\path [line] (Init)--(masterIni);
\path [line] (masterIni)--(IncNu);
\path [line] (IncNu)--(sub);
\path [line] (sub)--(phiCheck);
\path [line] (phiCheck) -- node [near start, xshift=1em] {Yes} (benders);
\path [line] (benders)--(master);
\path [line] (master)--(update);
\path [line] (update)--(convCheck);
\path [line] (convCheck)--node [near start, xshift=1em] {Yes} (end);
\path [line] (convCheck)-|node [near start, yshift=0.5em] {No}(maxIter);
\path [line] (maxIter)|-(IncNu);
\path [line] (phiCheck)--++  (3,0) node [near start, yshift=0.5em] {No} |- (convCheck);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows}
\tikzstyle{decision}=[diamond,draw]
\tikzstyle{line}=[draw,-latex']
\tikzstyle{elli}=[draw,ellipse]
\tikzstyle{block}=[draw,rectangle]
\scriptsize
\node [block, align=center] (masterm) {Solve master problem} ;
\node [block, below of=masterm, align=center, node distance=3em] (subm) {Solve sub problem};
\node [decision, below of=subm, align=center, node distance=6em] (check) {Is there\\ infeasibility?};
\node [elli, below of=check, align=center, node distance=6em] (end) {End};
\node [block, left of=end, xshift=-8em, yshift=10em, align=center] (cut) {Generate infeasibility cut};
%arrows
\path [line] (masterm)--(subm);
\path [line] (subm)--(check);
\path [line] (check)-- node [near start, xshift=1em] {No} (end);
\path [line] (check) -| node [near start, yshift=0.5em] {Yes} (cut);
\path [line] (cut) |- (masterm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. If I out both of them in them same floating figure the problem would be solved. But I need each one in a separate floating figure. In this case the problem arises. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Omidziaee: As Barbara Beeton had suggested, you should put together a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate reproduces the problem and edit the question to include that.  Once we can reproduce the problem you will get an answer that actually solves your particular issue.

Comment: @Omidziaee: If the solution worked for you please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) and perhaps [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).